# What is the function's return value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Could you please tell me what is Menu in the return statement below (return Menu;) ? Is it a variable (which is not defined) or the name of the inner function ?

```
var Menu = (function () {
    // A straightforward constructor. 
    function Menu(item_list, total_pages) {
        // The this keyword is mandatory.
        this.items = item_list;
        this.pages = total_pages;
    }
    // Methods
    Menu.prototype.list = function () {
        console.log("Our menu for today:");
        for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.items[i]);
        }
    };

    return Menu;
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a variable...?

Effectively. It comes from the function declaration:

```
function Menu(item_list, total_pages) {
    // The this keyword is mandatory.
    this.items = item_list;
    this.pages = total_pages;
}
```

Function declarations create what the spec calls a "binding" in the current execution context for the scope. It's effectively a variable.

So `return Menu;` returns the `Menu` function reference out of the anonymous function, and the outer `var Menu = ...` assignment assigns it to the `Menu` variable in the containing scope.

Answer (score 2):

Function declarations create a variable, in the scope of the function they are declared in, with a name that is the same as the name of the function itself.

So the return value is the function, which is the same as the value of the `Menu` variable.

```js
function return_function() {

  function foo() {
    console.log(1);
  }

  console.log(foo);

  var bar = foo;
  foo = 2;

  console.log(foo);

  return bar;

}

var baz = return_function();

baz();
```

Comment: We should just merge accounts. :-) Between us we have Skeet beat!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :)